# How to get latex in edge labels using dot2tex?

Tags: latex, dot2tex

The following example does not  work. The edge label doesn't show up properly.

```
DiGraph {
X [texlbl="$X$"]
Y [texlbl="$Y_s$"]
X -> YY [texlbl="$\int f(x) dx$"]
}
```

Looking for a way to get edge labels to work.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh just saw this deep in the pdf after I posted:

> If you use texlbl for edges, you have to provide a dummy label
>   attribute. Otherwise Graphviz will not generate the necessary code for
>   placing edge labels

So do this:

```
X -> YY [label="      ", texlbl="$asdf$"]
```